# jQuery script delayed by AJAX request - how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple responsive Wordpress Theme and I want only one page there, and the content loaded via AJAX, so I have an AJAX function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        jQuery("#mainnav a").click(function(){
            var post_link = jQuery(this).attr("href");
            jQuery("body").load(post_link);
        return false;
        });
    });
```

It's meant to load entire pages content (entire body) on clicking menu links. And it works well.

But the problem is I have a jQuery script responsible for centering content div:

```
(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery.fn.centerAlign = function() {
        return this.each(function(i){ 
            var w = jQuery(this).width();
            var ow = jQuery(this).outerWidth();
            var ml = (w + (ow - w)) / 2; 
            var h = jQuery(this).height();
            var oh = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
            var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;
        jQuery(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px");  
        jQuery(this).css("top", "50%");
        jQuery(this).css("margin-left", "-" + ml + "px");
        jQuery(this).css("left", "50%");
        jQuery(this).css("position", "absolute");
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#content").centerAlign(); 
});
```

That script centers the #content div at reload instatly, so I mean there is no delay. The div is centered from the start.

Problem is when I combine that scripts, because after AJAX loads the entire body, #content div is not positioned for ~1 second (in top-left corner of the page) and then it comes back to its place. So jQuery script works with a delay.

I coulnd't find a solution for that problem, .on and .live don't work for me. I think I could just load each page content into a #content div, not entire "body", but I don't know how to make it.

I'd appreciate if you can help me with that, so it will just resize the #content div with animation, not position it from start.

EDIT:
Ok, I ended up with such code:

```
jQuery(function(){
       jQuery("#mainnav a").click(function(e){
               var content=jQuery("#content");
               jQuery.ajax({
                   url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
                   dataType: "HTML",
                   beforeSend: function(){
                       content.empty();
                   },
                   success: function(){
                      content.load();
                   },
                   error : function(){
                       content.html("<p>Przepraszamy, ale strona jest chwilowo niedostępna</p>");
                   },
              });
              e.preventDefault();
       })
    })
```

It should work, but the problem is that I can't figure out what should I put in that lines:

```
success: function(){
                          content.load();
```

It workd up to that point. I clears the #content div but when I put content.load("#content"); it loads entire page, with menu and footer. And I want to load just #content content.

EDIT:

Ok. Firebug shows that this code is working, but there is nothing shown within the #content div in broswer window.

```
jQuery(function(){
       jQuery("#mainnav a").click(function(e){
               var content=jQuery("#content");
               var href=jQuery(this).attr('href');
               var text = jQuery(this).find('#content').html();

               jQuery.ajax({
                   url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
                   dataType: "HTML",
                   beforeSend: function(){
                       content.empty();
                   },
                    success: function(){
                        content
                            .html(text)
                            .centerAlign();
                    },
                   error : function(){
                       content.html("<p>Content Unavailable</p>");
                   },
              });
              e.preventDefault();
       })
    })
```

Comment: Can you hide the div ? Align it and then make it visible?

Comment: I want to add a jQuery function for that div to slide down, and slide up with reloaded content, but later. So I don't know if it could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could centerAlign `#content` before placing it inside body. Something like this

```
var $div = jQuery('<div/>').load(post_link);
$div.find('#content').first().centerAlign();
jQuery('body').html($div.html());
```

or only loading the content part

```
var $div = jQuery('<div/>').load(post_link);
jQuery('#content').first().html($div.find('#content').first().html());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem still occurs. It first centers the div and then it reloads entire body, so it has to center it again. It would work if I knew how to load just a "#content" div from each website.

Comment: Thanks. That is almost what I wanted do achieve. But it still loads entire page content (everything between <body> tags) into a #content so I have some kind of "inception", but without Brad Pitt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with your new code, you just need to fill out your `success` function:

```
success: function( html ){
    html = jQuery(html).find('#content').html();
    content.html(html).centerAlign();
},
```

or perhaps (using th1rdey3's idea):

```
success: function( html ){
    html = jQuery(html).find('#content').centerAlign().html();
    content.html( html );
},
```

Comment: That's not working for me. It does not load anything. Your previous function was working, but as I said, it was doubling the #content div.

Comment: Yeah, and the previous code (with `.load()`) wouldn't let you call your `centerAlign()` method either. For the new code, if you set a breakpoint inside the `success` method, what's the value you get for `html` before and after the first statement in the function?

Comment: It seems that problem is with that part of code: 

html = jQuery(html)
.find('#content')

I triend to put .centerAlign() into html function and it does not triggers. Like if the function stopped on that lines.

Comment: When I changed jQuery(html) to jQuery(document) for example, it triggered .centerAlign() function, so it seems jQuery(html) stops the function. But document or 'body' does not return anything.

Comment: Ok, I checked it with firebug and it shows that it loads the "#content" div... Firebug HTML preview shows it on place but it's not in the browser. So I don't really know what is wrong.